# In Levenberg–Marquardt, is forcing the Hessian to be positive definite OK?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, least-squares, numerical-optimization

I am often doing parameter estimation using the [Levenberg-Marquardt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) method, which involves solving the following linear system at each step:

$$(H + \lambda I) \delta = r_{i}$$

where $H$ is a square Hessian matrix, $I$ is an identity matrix, $r_{i}$ is residual vector (at $i$-th iteration), $\lambda$ is a damping factor, $\delta$ is improvement step to compute.

The $\lambda$ value is decreased when the step improved solution (reduced objective value) and increased otherwise. The $\lambda$ parameter can allow solving ill-posed problems as it makes the Hessian positive definite. In most cases $H$ is positive definite by itself, but sometimes not. **What to do in that case? Should I stop the iteration completely or increase lambda until $H$ becomes positive definite and solve the problem normally?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106277/levenberg-marquadt-near-the-minima-for-non-zero-residual-problems/) has been asked on MO a while ago. The answer is that you should neither stop the iteration, nor increase lambda. You could use a QR decomposition with pivoting, and set very small diagonal elements of R to zero (or use a singular value decomposition if this is a theoretical question). Another suggestion if this is too expensive was to add a small multiple of the identity to $J^TJ$ rather than by multiplying the diagonal elements by $(1+\lambda)$.

This last suggestion actually shows that your presentation of the problem is not accurate. Your are not really solving $(H+\lambda I)\delta=r_{i}$. (In that case, any $\lambda>0$ would make your problem positive definite, because the Hessian $H$ is semi-definite.) Instead, the Levenberg-Marquard method solves

$$(J^T J + \lambda\, \operatorname{diag}(J^T J)) \delta  = J^T [y - f(\boldsymbol \beta)]$$

Here, it can indeed happen that the problem stays singular for $\lambda>0$, but increasing $\lambda$ won't help.

Comment: Well the problem is actually that the model fits the data exactly with initial parameters, hence Jacobian is zero and so does Hessian. It was a programming bug because lambda happened to be zero as well and this made the system singular. Thanks for pointing out the effect of any positive lambda - that helped.

Comment: The problem actually appeared because I have implemented the method from "Numerical Recipes" book. They suggested to set lambda=0 after several improvements and go for "final solution"...

Comment: Okay I have solved it - the model fitted just perfectly on the points and hence the system was singular for $\lambda = 0$...